# Boost asio architecture document

Tags: boost, architecture, boost-asio

Does anyone know about a good architecture document for boost asio? All I find in the boost::documentation is about the api and how to use them. I would like to have a deeper understanding of the concepts behind them.

If I had overlooked the boost documentation, please let me know the correct resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some slides from a presentation by Michael Caisse at BoostCon 2010: [Getting Started with ASIO](http://www.cierelabs.com/slides/asio_presentation_with_story.pdf)

Here is the video of Michael giving that presentation, although the slides are easy to follow without watching the video: [Michael Caisse: An Asio Based Flash XML Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X45eBYkBv4)

For more general information on the design, read up on the [Proactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern)